# Is anyone using Netzke in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, netzke

I'm building an [Ext.js](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) application, and I'm planning on using rails for the backend. I'm trying to decide whether to use [Netzke](http://netzke.org/), or roll my own. Is anyone using Netzke in production?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes we do for a mid-size backoffice application localized in French, English and Thaï. We started with Netzke 0.6 & ExtJS3 and just finished upgrading to Netzke 0.7 & ExtJS4 (upgrading took 4 days with a little pain sometimes, but all in all it went pretty well). The development time for the application is about ~3 months with 3 junior developpers and me (got 100% test coverage + acceptance testing with Cucumber).

I've been investigating before choosing Netzke (JQuery UI, Roll-our-own UI, pure ExtJS, ...) and i'm very happy with the results (the customer too, which is much more important).

We are now happily starting another customer project with Netzke & ExtJS4.

Bests,

Answer (score 2):

Yes I do. For a smaller address management solution for <100 user with each >100k addresses.

My team also builded a larger application with extjs and rails (3 man years) and we used pure extjs and rails without any pre-build library.

I wouldn't suggest netzke for bigger projects. If you build something bigger, you better build your own framework that perfectly match your needs - not more not less. For smaller projects and prototypes neztke is really great.

If you have more detailed questions, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 2):

Netzke for admin interface very fast and rich solution.
At last release with ExtJS4 it became much useful and easy to build up.

Answer (score 2):

At my company we've used it for a big internal application. We've built literally hundreds of components - a lot of them being inherited components from netzke-basepack, but we also rolled our own from the ground up.

I think as of now it's by far the best solution to RIA with rails. The creator is very helpful and managed to build a growing and helpful community around the project.

Working with it is very rewarding - once you understand the core concepts you will be very quick plugging your components together to build great and interactive web apps. It can be a bit tough to polish it later though, due to the complexity of Ext JS itself (it's a complete application framework after all) - but with growing Ext JS knowledge this wasn't an issue in our project after some time.

I suggest you give it a try - there is no alternative to use rails with Ext JS IMHO :-)